# Will bootstrap 1 wont work in boostrap4 theme?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have an angular cli project in which the bootstrap version is 4 and recently i put a template with navbar which is done in bootstrap 1.The template is not working in my theme.Is this because of the version mismatch.Can anyone please help me.Thanks.

Comment: The CSS classes used in Bootstrap 1 & 4 are very different, that's why your ancient theme won't work in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Oh,then I think i should install bootstrap 1 in my theme.Is this the solution?

Comment: No, never use ancient version of Bootstrap. Make your own theme yourself.

Answer (score 0):

No it will not work, the classes and the code that drives Bootstrap has changed significantly between versions 1 to 4. You'll need to find a Bootstrap 4 solution, or build your own.

Answer (score 0):

No, It wont work, you have to use bootstrap 4